# Как сделать GET запрос на чистом JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, get

Как можно через javascript сделать GET запрос и получить от него ответ (html код некой страницы)?

Например: site.ru/index.php site.ru/auth.php

Нужно в index.php приписать на js скрипт, что бы он сделал get запрос на auth.php, и получил его исходный код.

Я делаю так:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open("GET", "http://ya.ru/r=" + Math.random(), true);
x.onreadystatechange = function ()alert(x.responseText);}
x.send(null);
</script>
```

Но открывает пустой алерт.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

На чистом JS всё получится. У вас опечатка: пропустили "{". И ловить надо событие `load` вместо `onreadystatechange`:

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open("GET", "/echo/json/", true);
x.onload = function (){
    alert( x.responseText);
}
x.send(null);
```

[Работающий пример](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/VWDAJ/).

Ну и [поинтересуйтесь](http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=JS%20кроссдоменный%20запрос) кроссдоменными запросами — «нельзя просто так взять и» обратиться к другому сайту, чем тот, с которого скрипт.

Comment: fetch('http://192.168.0.100/console/send?text=777 3'); Позволит обращаться на другие сайты.